# Cannot convert json file to desire pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

I had been tried to load my JSON file to pandas data frame but I can't get my desired output. Below is my code and my desired output.

Under the code is an example of my dataset. This is the error that I faced during running my code: KeyError: 'pose2d'

```
df =  pd.read_json('/content/gdrive/MyDrive/FYP/Drink.Fromglass_p02_r00_v06_c05_pose3d.json', orient='records')
bn = pd.DataFrame(df.frames.values.tolist())['pose2d'],['pose3d']
df
```

{"njts": 13, "K": 5, "frames": [[{"pose2d": [401.1044006347656, 383.12872314453125, 418.0142822265625, 411.3098449707031, 451.2345275878906, 449.1337585449219, 438.6675720214844, 427.89361572265625, 461.6995544433594, 456.29901123046875, 491.7781677246094, 487.2626647949219, 490.89776611328125, 269.81915283203125, 271.0229797363281, 240.58421325683594, 236.54083251953125, 243.6001739501953, 250.42176818847656, 226.494140625, 232.65614318847656, 232.06121826171875, 251.1204071044922, 222.17092895507812, 236.52366638183594, 205.56300354003906], "pose3d": [0.5264420569874346, 0.5680492878891528, 0.3639590204693377, 0.348236417863518, 0.0860291444696486, 0.11183053301647305, 0.18630200484767556, 0.226348212454468, 0.059024347458034754, 0.05218803742900491, -0.1013507335446775, -0.09650894394144416, -0.1363151310943067, -0.27886097971349955, -0.2906324500218034, -0.028285750187933445, -0.0621380964294076, -0.05211269948631525, -0.13107324857264757, 0.0927228843793273, 0.02507274504750967, 0.051666310988366604, -0.1013856390491128, 0.13576482888311148, 0.047421119175851345, 0.25779136177152395, 0.5459041241556406, 0.4584615770727396, 0.3058544937521219, 0.20824461616575718, 0.16991993971168995, 0.027482325211167336, 0.14647855795919895, -0.09192127548158169, 0.1281041707843542, -0.15487194620072842, -0.02632092498242855, -0.17108133994042873, -0.21561226807534695]}], [{"pose2d": [403.4307861328125, 386.0056457519531, 417.3297424316406, 414.7776184082031, 453.4864807128906, 456.2215881347656, 455.3381652832031, 438.4986572265625, 468.7621154785156, 466.32135009765625, 490.6894226074219, 491.3076477050781, 492.6455078125, 282.2063903808594, 283.7082214355469, 251.8082275390625, 247.9337615966797, 249.96572875976562, 257.91583251953125, 218.42018127441406, 247.42051696777344, 231.50238037109375, 258.23040771484375, 218.34512329101562, 233.8579864501953, 198.28672790527344], "pose3d": [0.5316048903041519, 0.5671673161559738, 0.37763351626927033, 0.346489493327681, 0.09359736164333299, 0.09858725691447034, 0.14767816342646256, 0.20154458709293976, 0.03667460061842576, 0.024809014576021582, -0.09310993127292022, -0.09907468728488311, -0.12968565098708495, -0.3095469195395708, -0.3282767403870821, -0.05611537583172321, -0.10412886925041676, -0.06272503174841404, -0.1489740777760744, 0.13157951645553112, -0.040350014343857765, 0.05784389190375805, -0.12501616962254047, 0.15424510650336742, 0.057454003021121025, 0.27937248162925243, 0.5229081306606531, 0.4335366580635309, 0.28675136901438236, 0.18498505093157291, 0.17118931002914906, 0.013212369754910469, 0.14590882696211338, -0.1047151293605566, 0.15624199248850346, -0.16647296212613583, -0.011685876175761223, -0.1727158036082983, -0.20240946672856808]}]]}

[desire output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqVfK.png)

Answer (score 1):

The issue at hand seems to be that the data is more deeply nested than you are accessing it. Inside the column frames it is tucked inside a list as different dictionaries. You are trying to access the dictionary ['pose2d'], but you are not deep enough in the data.
You might try the following to get some data out (access the 0th row of frames, which is a list, access its first index, which is a dictionary, and get out the data for "pose2d":

```
bn = pd.DataFrame(df.frames[0][0]["pose2d"])
```

However, this will give you only data from the first list entry and only from one dictionary entry (pose2d), and will also not store the column name. If you would try to save each dictionary directly into a DataFrame (`pd.DataFrame(df.frames[0][0])` ) , you also run into issues since pose2d and pose3d are not the same length of list.
Personally I would do something like this, which gives both the data for pose2d and pose3d in d2 and d3 resp.:

```
# Save values in a list
pose2dvalues = []
pose3dvalues = []
# Loop over rows of column frames
for i in df.frames:
    # Save datalist to list (it is now in a list of lists)
    pose2dvalues.append(i[0]["pose2d"])
    pose3dvalues.append(i[0]["pose3d"])

# Make a dataframe from list of lists, need to transpose since default makes rows columns
d2 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(pose2dvalues).transpose()
d3 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(pose3dvalues).transpose()

# Set column names based on number of pose2d/pose3d values parsed
d2.columns = ["pose2d_"+str(i+1) for i in range(len(pose2dvalues))]
d3.columns = ["pose3d_"+str(i+1) for i in range(len(pose3dvalues))]

print(d2.head(),d3.head())
```

Comment: It works! Thank you so much! That's the output that I want. I already figured it for many days... May I know is it possible for me to put append the whole pose3d column right after the column pose2d? Also, is it can be also used for multiple files like this?

Comment: Normally, you can add columns to a dataframe like this: d2["pose3d_1"] = d3["pose3d_1"]. However in your case the columns are of different length and that means the shortest column will be filled with NaN values after its values have run out or the longest column will be cut off. This is really up to you and your needs. Regarding multiple files: You can loop over the files and perform the same transformation creating different dataframes for each and then add all dataframes to a list and combine them using pd.concat :https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html

Comment: I tried this: d2["pose3d_1"] = d3["pose3d_1"] to add under the "d2 and d3.columns = ["pose3d_"+str(i+1) for i in range(len(pose3dvalues))]" but I only get pose3d_1 only after pose2d_42. And for multiple files, if I really want to load multiple files, I need to give every file an unique dataframe or I can just use the same method like load all the file into one dataframe and use what is given from you to do the "for i in df.frames" as above.